# jQuery promise, how to check then() is truly after when()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

It may only a lesson I learnt in a hard way, but I just want to confirm this with everyone.

```
function a() {
  var dtd = $.Deferred(); 
  console.log('a');
  setTimeout(() => {
    dtd.resolve(); 
  }, 5000);
  return dtd.promise(); 
}  
function b() {
  var dtd = $.Deferred(); 
  console.log('b');
  setTimeout(() => {
    dtd.resolve(); 
  }, 5000);
  return dtd.promise(); 
}    

$.when(a()).then(b()).done(function () {console.log('c');});
```

Only `c` is printed after the delay, `a` and `b` aren't.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02ek4gw6/12/).

Is it the way it is? Thanks.

Comment: It is **always** the way it is. [No matter where you go... there you are](https://i.imgflip.com/1rpl20.jpg).

Comment: what is your expected output here? a will print after 5s, then b & c will print after 5s?

Comment: I thought it should be a...5s...b...5s...c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `$.when()` should be a Promise - which you did right, because `a()` returns a Promise.

But the **`.then()` actually takes a function as argument**. That is, you should pass `b`, not the result of `b()`.

The expression `.then(b())` executes `b()` *right away*, so it won't wait 5s until `a()`'s promise is resolved. When you have `.then(b)`, the call `b()` will only happen after `a()`'s promise is resolved, which is what you want.

So just changing `.then(b())` to `.then(b)` will run as you expected (print `a`, wait 5s, print `b`, wait another 5s, print `c`):

```js
function a() {
  var dtd = $.Deferred(); 
  console.log('a');
  setTimeout(() => {
    dtd.resolve(); 
  }, 5000);
  return dtd.promise(); 
}  
function b() {
  var dtd = $.Deferred(); 
  console.log('b');
  setTimeout(() => {
    dtd.resolve(); 
  }, 5000);
  return dtd.promise(); 
}    
$.when(a()).then(b).done(function () {console.log('c');});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```